# c++ method returning 0 from c# dllimport call

Tags: c#, c++, reference, return-value, dllimport

I am making a call to functions and all I am getting is 0, this is 3rd party software that has been used for years so I know it is right. here is the c++ header file:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
int __stdcall initialise();
int __stdcall closedown();
int __stdcall WGS84ToLocal(double * lat, double * longt, int d);
int __stdcall LocalToWGS84(double * lat, double * longt, int d);
int __stdcall OSGB36ToOSGBGrid(double lat, double longt, double * east, double * north);
int __stdcall OSGBGridToOSGB36(double east, double north, double * lat, double * longt);
```

and here is my code

```
  class Program
{
    public static double lon = 50.82011492;
    public static double lat = 0.117981131;
    public static double north = 50.82011492;
    public static double east = 0.117981131;
    public static Int32 OGB_M = 150;
    public static int iErr = 0;

    [DllImport("TTDatum3.Dll", EntryPoint = "WGS84ToLocal", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern Int32 WGS84ToLocal([In, Out]ref double lat, [In, Out] ref double lon, Int32 datum);

    [DllImport("TTDatum3.Dll", EntryPoint="LocalToWGS84", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern Int32 LocalToWGS84([In,Out]ref double lat,[In,Out] ref double lon, Int32 datum);

    [DllImport("TTDatum3.Dll", EntryPoint = "OSGB36ToOSGBGrid", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern Int32 OSGB36ToOSGBGrid( double lat, double lon, [In,Out] ref double east, [In,Out] ref double north);

    [DllImport("TTDatum3.Dll", EntryPoint = "OSGBGridToOSGB36", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern Int32 OSGBGridToOSGB36(double east, double north, [In,Out] ref double lat,[In,Out]  ref double lon);



    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

       iErr = OSGBGridToOSGB36(east, north, ref lon, ref lat);
       Console.WriteLine(iErr);
       iErr = LocalToWGS84(ref lon, ref lat, OGB_M);
       Console.WriteLine(iErr);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the order of lat and lon reversed in your Main vs your method's above.  No idea if that's the cause of your issues but it's 1 input.

What are you expecting iErr to return?
Fix that part and then provide an update please.

Comment: no dosnt matter at the moment I am just testing, ierr will return a converted long lat from OSGB36 to WGS84